# Adding an exception to tell the user in the channel they dont have permission

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I don't get any errors with this code but bot still wont tell the non-admin user they dont have permission, it just stays in the terminal, what am i doing wrong in this that bot wont say that or what would i need to change to fix that, also using discord.py rewrite

```
bans a user with a reason
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Keyblade Master","Foretellers")
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):

    adminroles = ("Keyblade Master","Foretellers")

    try:
        if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
            await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
            return

        elif reason == None:
            reason = "being a jerk!"
            message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for  {reason}"
            await member.send(message)
            # await ctx.guild.ban(member)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is banned!") 
    except commands.errors.MissingAnyRole(adminroles): 
        await ctx.channel.send("You do not have permission to do that!")
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors raised during command invocation, before the callback is called (like `CheckFailure`, `UserInputError`, and their derivatives) need to be handled by a separate [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling), because the code that is failing is not actually in your `try` block.

```
@client.command(name="ban")
@commands.has_any_role("Keyblade Master","Foretellers")
async def ban_command(ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):

    adminroles = ("Keyblade Master","Foretellers")
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
        return

    elif reason == None:
        reason = "being a jerk!"

    message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for  {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    # await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} is banned!") 

@ban_command.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingAnyRole):
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to do that!")
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped, and thanks for the link, ill use that if any other similar errors happen in future commands